# How to disable a child item in a listview(make its color gray and unclickable)

Tags: android, listview

in my application, there is a listview, and clicking each item of it leads to an operation.

but in some situation, some operation can not be done.

how to disable a child item in a listview (make its color gray and unclickable)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable items in a List View???](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662358/how-to-disable-items-in-a-list-view) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907335/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183610

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should override [isEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html#isEnabled%28int%29) in your adapter. Just keep track of the items you want to disable and return the correct value for them.

Comment: But how to make it gray colored so it looks disabled.

Comment: I managed to mark the view gray by setting its alpha value to 0.5 when the view is disabled.