# ListView item button Disable

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have one custom baseadapter for listView. Now I have buttons on each listView item. I need to disable the button onclick of them. But when I'm clicking on one of the buttons, multiple buttons are disabling on the list. I'm attaching the code .

```
@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final int k = arg0;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_element, null);

    }
    TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    name.setText(arrayList.get(arg0).getName());
    TextView phone = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    phone.setText(arrayList.get(arg0).getPhoneNum());

    Button request = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);


    request.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Update the local database of Request table
            databaseHelper.insertRequestTable(new Person(arrayList.get(k).getName(), arrayList.get(k).getPhoneNum()));
            ((Button)arg0).setEnabled(false);
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: there are so many question similar to this, such as: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2662358/2145360, http://stackoverflow.com/q/5938514/2145360, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2183610/2145360 and many other. try to look on it.

Comment: try request.setEnabled(false)

Comment: I am getting similar problem with Expandable List View, not on normal listview

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Already tried that, but getting the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
Button request = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
// this refers to all button in the list view you

// viewholder holds reference of bojects 
public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView phone;
    Button request;
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
final int k = arg0;
if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_element, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    // save the references in the holder 
    holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.phone = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    holder.request = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    // save this references to view so the you can get it back to set some thing
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    // get the reference back 
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

holder.name.setText(arrayList.get(arg0).getName());

holder.phone.setText(arrayList.get(arg0).getPhoneNum());
// this will refer to button you want not all
holder.request.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Update the local database of Request table
        databaseHelper.insertRequestTable(new Person(arrayList.get(k).getName(), arrayList.get(k).getPhoneNum()));
        ((Button)arg0).setEnabled(false);
    }
});
return convertView;
}
```

GitHub Project: https://github.com/rathodvikas10/android-examples/tree/master/ListView

Comment: note that you will have to re enable the button at that position, it will not be clickable once it is set to false.

Comment: Code only answers aren't generally good on SO. Please add an explanation as to what you changed and how it provides a solution.

Comment: @VikasRathod The problem is still there. A new thing is happening now, the listView elements are changing now.

Comment: ok in the first code i posted, i did not added convertView.setTag(holder); now m bit busy i will post you full android project.