# Android: How to disable ListView?

Tags: android, listview, highlighting, android-arrayadapter

I have a list view and want each cell in my within it to be disabled so that when you tap on it the text colors stay the same.

But I want it to be scrollable.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662358/how-to-disable-items-in-a-list-view) might be of help. The general approach is to disable all the items instead of the whole view. Essentially:

- Inherit from `ArrayAdapter` (or any other adapter)
- Override `isEnabled(int position)` to return `false`
- Override `areAllItemsEnabled()` to return `false`

Answer (score 2):

all the easier! list.setEnabled(false)

Comment: This makes the list un-scrollable it doesn't merely disable the items.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding android:clickable="false" to the list view's rows?