# How to customize listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

In my game application am using a listview to select levels. Am activating this listview item onclickable if the previous level is cleared. I need to differentiate the activated and unactivated level's in listview.How can i make it possible? If possible suggest me tutorial. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put your logic for activated and unactivated levels in `getView` method ,check if activated then inflated activated row otherwisw unactivated row.

Answer (score 0):

First check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183610/android-how-to-disable-list-items-on-list-creation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662358/how-to-disable-items-in-a-list-view) stackoverflow questions and try some code and post your question if you have any problems. Please try first.

You can use `setClickable(false)` to disable touch events on list. To make it look disabled, you can change the textView colors in the list items and get such effects.

Thanks