# Disable ripple effect on Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, material-design, ripple

I have a simple listview that has some listitems. Currently, to make the items ripple on touch, I just added `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` to the listview.

This works perfectly.

However, some of the list items are headers and should not show ripples because they do not have an action associated with them. How can I disable the ripple effect for *only* the headers?

The listview contains linearlayouts for the rows and the headers.

I tried the following on the header with no success:

- setting `clickable` to false
- setting `listSelector` to null.
- setting `focusable` to false.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How are you adding the header? Can I see that line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly [a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662358/how-to-disable-items-in-a-list-view). But as a summary: try disabling those elements in your adapter. You can use the [.areAllItemsEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#areAllItemsEnabled()) and [.isEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#isEnabled(int)) callbacks for this purpose.